# Update branch with the same changes but different commit

Tags: git, github

I'm contributing to the project in GitHub, so I created a PR with my changes from my fork. My changes are good, but I use wrong 'user.email' in my configs, so I updated my local configs by this command `git config --global user.email test@example.com` and now I need to update my PR branch, but I didn't make any changes except email, so what is the best way to update remote PR branch with the same commit(same changes) as the latest commit?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by pushing the same commit again as latest commit? If its already present ,git will not allow this .

Comment: as I mentioned I need to keep changes the same as in the latest commit (I don't want to create ambiguous commits just to change internal git config)
I understand that I can't do it for the same commit, I tried to create new one and fixup with the parent, but it keep using email which I used to create parent commit

Comment: Can you run this : git config user.email ? Does it give old email address or a new mail address? Also try running the git config command without using —global flag and then do git push again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you need to copy the old (and mostly-OK, except for that one error) commit to a new-and-improved commit.  We'll use `git commit --amend --reset-author` to do this.  You'll also need one force-push.

#### Background

The main Git command that copies a commit is `git cherry-pick`.  The rebase method, mentioned in [karan dhillon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65781626/1256452), often *uses* cherry-pick internally, so it works out the same.  There's just one problem: cherry-pick uses one of Git's special features to preserve the original author.<sup>1</sup>

There's no easy way to *defeat* this special feature with cherry-pick or rebase.  Fortunately, there *is* an easy way to do it by using `git commit --amend`.  This command is not *meant* to copy a commit, but because no commit can actually be changed—ever: not even by Git itself—the way `--amend` works has, or more precisely, *can have*, the side effect of copying a commit ... and `git commit` has `--reset-author` as an option.

So, let's run through the sequence of commands you used to make a Pull Request (note that PRs are not a Git thing but rather a GitHub thing).  You:

- made a *fork*, which is a GitHub-side clone with some special added GitHub features, including the ability to make PRs;
- cloned the fork to your own computer;
- made a new branch name in your computer's clone;
- made one new commit on this branch;
- used `git push` to send this commit to your GitHub fork; and
- used GitHub's "make a Pull Request" system to make a PR from your GitHub fork to the Git repository on GitHub from which you forked your GitHub clone (whew!).

(Exercise: count the number of Git repositories involved here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The special feature works by making use of the fact that each commit has not just one name-email-and-timestamp in it, but rather *two:* one is called the *author* and the other is called the *committer*.  These two are the same in a fresh new from-scratch commit, but when you copy an old commit, cherry-pick—and rebase—preserve the original author, and only provide a new committer trio.

This feature allows Git to attribute a commit to two different people; that's standard across all Git setups.  Note that GitHub have also added additional scanning to look for "trailer" lines in commits so that they can list a commit as being authored by multiple people.  While this feature is *enabled by* the trailer scanning capabilities built into Git, it too is a GitHub feature.

---

#### A drawing

Here's what you have, in your own Git repository, as your series of commits:

```
...--G--H   <-- mainline [probably `master` or `main`]
         \
          I   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
```

Commit `H`—the `H` here stands for *hash-ID*, some big ugly Git hash ID that we don't even want to have to think about—was and still is the *last* commit on the main-line.  When you created a new branch name, your new branch name *also* pointed to commit `H`, but then you made a new commit `I`, causing your branch to advance.

You then sent commit `I` to your GitHub fork and created, in your GitHub fork, the branch name `your-branch`, to match the branch name in your own Git on your own computer.  When you use `git push` or `git fetch`, you hook two Gits up to each other: whichever one is sending transfers new *commits* to the other, and whichever one is *receiving* then has to create or update some *name* by which we can find the commits, because hash IDs are too ugly for humans to deal with.

We now need to copy commit `I` to a new-and-improved commit.  While cherry-pick is the obvious way to do that, it doesn't work because of that special feature.  So we'll (ab?)use `git commit --amend`.

What `git commit --amend` does is to make a *new* commit from whatever is in Git's *index*.  The index—which Git also calls the *staging area*—provides the *snapshot* part of a new commit.  When you made commit `I`, you made it from Git's index, and it's still there in Git's index because you're still on commit `I`.  I like to say that the index is your *proposed next commit*.  This is not completely accurate (because the index is *more* than just that) but it's a good way to think about it.

A regular `git commit`:

- gathers a log message from you, to put in the new commit's metadata;
- adds to this metadata your name and email address from your configured entries;
- uses `git write-tree` to turn whatever is in the index—your proposed next commit—into a snapshot;
- adds the metadata, including the current commit as the new commit's parent;
- writes all of this out *as* a commit, gaining a new unique hash ID; and last,
- writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name.

A `git commit --amend` changes this process slightly:

- The new commit's *log message* defaults to the existing commit's log message, which you can then edit (see the `--edit` and `--no-edit` options).
- The new commit's *author* defaults to the old commit's author: we fix this with `--reset-author`.
- The new commit's *parent* hash ID in its metadata is not the *current commit*.  Instead, it's the *current commit's parent* (or parents, if the current commit is a merge commit).

The rest is basically the same.  So `git commit --amend` will make a new commit from whatever is in Git's index,<sup>2</sup> which is the same as what's in commit `I`.  But the parent of this new commit—let's call it `I'` since it's so similar to `I`—will be `I`'s parent, i.e., `H`.  The `--reset-author` will make Git use your configured name-and-email (and the current date-and-time) as the author, as if this were any other all-new-commit, too.

Once the commit is done, `git commit` will write the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name as usual.  So we'll end up with this:

```
          I'  <-- your-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- mainline [probably `master` or `main`]
         \
          I   [abandoned]
```

---

<sup>2</sup>There's a further trick one can use: the `--only` option, with no files listed, causes the amend to use what's in the to-be-amended commit instead of what's in Git's index.  We don't need this trick here though.

---

#### Reduced to a recipe

Assuming you have not done any `git checkout`s so that you are still on `your-branch` and hence on your existing commit `I` as drawn above, the complete sequence of commands is:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit
git push origin -f HEAD
```

We add the `--no-edit` here to avoid needing to use our editor to change the commit message copied from `I`.  (If you'd *like* to change it, leave out the `--no-edit` to get the default `--edit` behavior.)

Once the commit is made, we wish to send it to our GitHub fork.  The Git at GitHub would reject our attempt to update our name `your-branch`, though, because this will discard commit `I`.  But that's exactly what we want that Git to do: discard commit `I` in favor of its new-and-improved replacement `I'`.  So we add `-f` (the short spelling for `--force`).  To avoid having to type out the branch name again this time, we can just use `HEAD` here as the entire *refspec* argument.

Once GitHub receive the new commit and update their name `your-branch`, they will automatically update the PR, so there's no further action required here.  (That's a GitHub feature, of course, since the PR itself is a GitHub feature.)

Comment: thanks @torek for the detailed answer, I wan not aware about --reset-author flag, it works for me now

Answer (score 0):

If the PR only has a single commit and not bunch of them, then simply create a new empty commit that will have this new email.

Then run the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

here choose this newly created empty commit and `fixup` or `meld` with the last commit.

Then force push again in the PR as follows:

```
git push -f
```

Your PR will have the new commit, with the same message but with a new email. The PR will state that a force push happened, but any changes will be preserved.

Comment: thanks for the answer, in my case email was changed for this property user.email in ~/.gitconfig, so I have nothing to commit  as it's only internal git config

Comment: My empty commit i mean make a trivial change, for example add a space or whatever. The purpose is to create a commit with this new config info and fixup with the previous one.

Comment: just tried it with fixup, it creates a new commit with the same changes as you described above, but still keep using email from parent commit, for child commits it looks good, but to make it work I need to somehow apply it to the parent

Comment: Writing `head` in lowercase like this is a bad habit: while it mostly works on most Windows and Mac setups, it doesn't work right in added work-trees, and it does not work at all on a typical Linux setup. If you don't like typing out `HEAD` in all-caps, consider using the `@` synonym: `@~2` and `HEAD~2` mean the same thing but `@` doesn't require holding down the shift key so long. :-)

Comment: @torek fixed it!